# Python and JavaScript link

Tags: javascript, electron, revitpythonshell

I was trying to link the Javascript Electron app with the python deep learning engine by using PYthon-shell. But I don't know where to go now.

This is the python code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

from sklearn.preprocessing import label
import sys




model = load_model('model.h5')
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

img = cv2.imread('file/4/1.jpg')

img = np.reshape(img, [1, 28, 28, 3])
class1 = model.predict_classes(img)

print("the pridicted number is", class1 + 1)

sys.stdout.flush()
```

The javascript code looks like:

```
 let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
  var path = require('path');
function getPrediction() {
 
  
  let pyInput ={
    scriptPath : path.join('/../BackEnd/'),
    pyPaht :path.join( '/../BackEnd/')

  }


PythonShell = new PythonShell('numbers.py', pyInput);


pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
    alert(message);
  })

}
```

Here is the error output:

```
index.js:35 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PythonShell' before initialization
    at jsFunction
```

Comment: And what is wrong? Update the question with errors/outputs so people can try to answer. ;)

Comment: here is the error out output "index.js:35 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PythonShell' before initialization at jsFunction

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure

```js
PythonShell = new PythonShell('numbers.py', pyInput);
```

should read

```js
pyshell = new PythonShell('numbers.py', pyInput);
```

Also you've misspelt `alert` as `aler`.

Comment: thank you for it. The error message also showing that like this at 'join' method
8index.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
    at getPrediction (index.js:31)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:29)

Comment: I don't think I can solve that problem without an in-depth knowledge of PythonShell. You should pose it as a new question.

Comment: It could be a misspelling: `pyPaht` -> `pyPath`?

Comment: It sounds like `path.join` is failing. Perhaps `require('path')` is not returning an object.